# How to update a field which is indexed?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I want to update a field in Cassandra which is indexed using phantom scala sdk like:

```
this.update.where(_.id eqs folderId)
      .and(_.owner eqs owner)
      .modify(_.parent setTo parentId)
```

the parent field is a indexed field in table. But the operation is not allowed when compile the code, there will have compile exception like:

```
[error] C:\User\src\main\scala\com\autodesk\platform\columbus\cassandra\DataItem.scala:161: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.websudos.phantom.column.ModifiableColumn[T]
```

The error is caused by update the field which is indexed.

My workaround is to delete the record and insert a new record to "update" the record.

Is there a better way for the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to update a field that is part of the primary key, because if you do so you are rendering Cassandra unable to ever re-compose the hash of the row you are updating.

Read [**here**](http://blog.websudos.com/2014/08/23/a-series-on-cassandra-part-2-indexes-and-keys/) for details on the topic. In essence, if you had a `HashMap[K, V]` what you are trying to do is update the `K`, but in doing so you will never be able to retrieve the same `V` again.

So in Cassandra, just like in the `HashMap`, an update to an index is done with a `DELETE` and then a new `INSERT`. That's why phantom intentionally prevents you from compiling your query, I wrote those compile time restrictions in for the specific purposes of preventing invalid CQL.

Comment: So, there is no other way except delete and add. Since delete and add are  two operations ,is there any way to make the two operations atomic executed?

Comment: @wherby No, you still have to go the normal Cassandra way. A delete will result in tombstones etc, the normal way. Yes you might still have zombies, but ideally after updating you never query for the original id again. Also, you can control consistency to address this.

Comment: You can use `logged batches` to have some kind of "lightweight transactions" for delete+insert operations.